# Where does the C++ standard describe the casting of pointers to primitives?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer

In the excellent blog post [What Every Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), the section "Violating Type Rules" says:

> It is undefined behavior to cast an int* to a float* and dereference it (accessing the "int" as if it were a "float"). C requires that these sorts of type conversions happen through memcpy: using pointer casts is not correct and undefined behavior results. The rules for this are quite nuanced and I don't want to go into the details here (there is an exception for char*, vectors have special properties, unions change things, etc).

I'd like to understand the rules in their full nuancedness.  Where are they in the C++11 spec?  Or failing that, the C spec (C90, C99, C11)?

In the C++11 spec linked from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents), N3485, I'm looking in 5.2.10 "Reinterpret cast" but don't see language for an exception for char* or unions. So that's probably not the right place.  So where is the right place?

Comment: In C++, you should look at the different types of casts in the standard sections 5.4, safely derived pointers 3.7.4.3, static_cast 5.2.9, reinterpret_cast 5.2.10...

Comment: serendipity: yesterday's latest STL [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-8-of-n) on Channel 9 contains a segment on C++ casts (including references to the Standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule you're looking for is in §3.10/10 (in C++11):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object
>   through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the
>   behavior is undeﬁned:
>   — the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a cv-qualiﬁed version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type similar (as deﬁned in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualiﬁed version of the dynamic type
>   of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic
>   data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>   or contained union),
>
> — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> — a char or unsignedchar type.

There are different types (or motivations) for undefined
behavior.

In the case of casting an `int*` to `float*` and then
dereferencing it, it is clear that the standard cannot define
it, since what might happen will depend on the architecture, and
the value of the `int`.  On the other hand, the quoted paragraph
is completely wrong—using `memcpy` to do the conversion is
also undefined behavior, for largely the same reasons.

One of the motivations for undefined behavior is to
allow implementations to define it, in a manner that makes sense
for the target architecture, *if* such exists.  This is such
a case.  A compiler which intentionally causes it to fail is
defective.  Of course, if we suppose 32 bit 2's complement
`int`, and 32 bit IEEE `float`, we may expect certain values of
the `int` to correspond to trapping NaN, which will cause the program
to fail.  This is part of the reason the behavior is
undefined; to allow such things to happen.  But if we are
familiar with the low level details of the hardware,
it *should* work as expected, *provided* the compiler can see
the cast.
If it doesn't, this is a QoI problem with the compiler, and such
a compiler should be avoided for such types of work.

As hinted at above, this particular case, and in fact, in all
cases which involve type punning (writing to one member of
a union, and reading from another, for example), do pose
a problem, to which the standard has yet to find adequate
wording.  The problem occurs because normally, the compiler is
allowed to assume that pointers to different types (except
character types) do not alias; that an `int*` can never point to
the same object as a `float*`.  And proving that two pointers
cannot alias is important for optimization.  A compiler that
breaks code where the pointer cast or the union is clearly visible is
just broken, even if the standard says it is undefined behavior.
A compiler that breaks code where all it sees are two pointers
to unrelated types is understandable, even in cases where the
standard says the behavior is well defined.

Using `memcpy` avoids this problem by using two different
objects, which don't alias.  It still encounters undefined
behavior because putting the bit pattern of an `int` into
a `float`, then accessing the float, doesn't have any defined
behavior.  (Or vice-versa; I know of at least one machine where
copying the bits of a `float` into an `int` may result in an
illegal `int` value.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Regarding memcpy, section 3.9 par 2 says "For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object
holds a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array
of char or unsigned char."

Comment: @MartinC.Martin Yes.  Character types are special, and neither `char` nor `unsigned char` are allowed to have trapping values.  Similarly, when the compiler sees a `char*`, it has to assume that the pointer might alias any other type.

Comment: I've never seen a machine that had illegal `int` values, which one was it?

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard says that if a certain behavior is not explicitly described to be defined, then it is implicitly undefined. Since the standard does not define the behavior of casting an `int*` to `float*`, then it is implicitly undefined.

Comment: Where does it say that casting to/from a char* is defined?

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` on pointers is defined in terms of `static_cast` on `void` pointers

**5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]>**

> 7 An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer
>   of a diﬀerent type. 70 When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is
>   converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is `static_cast<cv
>   T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout
>   types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than
>   those of T1, or if either type is void. Converting a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are
>   object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer
>   conversion is unspeciﬁed.

**5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]**

> 13 A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T,” where T is an object type and cv2
>   is the same cv-qualiﬁcation as, or greater cv-qualiﬁcation than, cv1.
>   The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
>   destination type. A value of type pointer to object converted to
>   “pointer to cv void” and back, possibly with diﬀerent cv-qualiﬁcation,
>   shall have its original value.

Comment: Are primitive types (char, int, float) also considered object types?  Or is "object" reserved for classes/structs?  In colloquial usage, people often distinguish between primitive types and objects.

Comment: Section 1.8 seems to suggest that primitive types are, indeed, objects.