# Were all implementations of std::vector non-portable before std::launder?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, placement-new

When `emplace_back()` is called on `std::vector` instance, an object is created in a previously allocated storage. This can be easily achieved with placement-new, which is perfectly portable.
But now, we need to access the emplaced element without invoking undefined behavior.

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003727/does-this-really-break-strict-aliasing-rules)
I learned that there are two ways of doing this

1. use the pointer returned by placement-new:
   `auto *elemPtr  = new (bufferPtr) MyType();`
2. or, since C++17, [std::launder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382501/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdlaunder/39382728#39382728) the pointer casted from `bufferPtr`
   `auto *elemPtr2 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(bufferPtr));`

The second approach can be easily generalized to the case, where we have a lot of objects
emplaced in adjacent memory locations, as in `std::vector`. But what people did before C++17?
One solution would be to store pointers returned by placement-new in a separate dynamic array.
While this is certainly legal, I don't think it really implements std::vector [besides, it's a crazy idea to separately store all the addresses that we know already].
The other solution is to store `lastEmplacedElemPtr` inside `std::vector`, and remove an appropriate integer from it -- but since we don't really have an array of `MyType` objects this is probably also undefined. In fact, an example from [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers) claims that if we have two pointers
of the same type that compare equal, and one of them can be dereferenced safely, dereferencing  the other can be still undefined.

So, was there a way to implement std::vector in a portable way before C++17?
Or maybe std::launder is indeed a crucial piece of C++ when it comes to placement-new,
that was missing since C++98?

I'm aware that this question is superficially similar to a lot of other questions on SO, but as far as I can tell none of them explains how to legally iterate over objects constructed by placement-new. In fact, this is all a bit confusing.  For instance comments in the example
form [cppreference documentation of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) `std::aligned_storage`
seem to suggest that there has been some change between C++11 and C++17, and a simple
aliasing-violating `reinterpret_cast` was legal before C++17 [without the need for `std::launder`].  Similarly, in the example from [documentation of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) `std::malloc`
they simply do a pointer arithmetic on a pointer returned by `std::malloc` (after `static_cast` to the correct type).

By contrast, according to the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429476/reinterpret-cast-char-and-undefined-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1)  when it comes to placement-new and `reinterpret_cast`:

> There have been some significant rule clarifications since C++11
> (particularly [basic.life]). But the intent behind the rules hasn't
> changed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216946/discussion-on-question-by-adrian-were-all-implementations-of-stdvector-non-por).

Comment: Somewhat related question and answer, [c++ - Does reinterpret_casting std::aligned_storage* to T* without std::launder violate strict-aliasing rules? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735657/does-reinterpret-casting-stdaligned-storage-to-t-without-stdlaunder-violat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC after [P0593R6](https://wg21.link/p0593r6) and [P1971R0/RU007](https://wg21.link/p1971r0#RU007), both merged into C++20 and considerable as defect reports against previous revisions, a portable `std::vector` implementation doesn't need `std::launder`.

First, after the `allocate` function of the given allocator (which might call `operator new`, `std::malloc`, or something like them) returned, a `value_type[N]` array (where `N` is equal to the requested number passed to `allocate`) is implicitly created within the allocated storage (thanks to P0593R6), and thus pointer arithmetic is valid. Even if the elements may be unconstructed.

Second, when we use placement-new without `std::launder`, the constructed objects can be treated as array elements, as new objects transparently replace the array elements even if the element type has const/reference non-static data members (thanks to P1971R0/RU007 and subsequent fixes in [P2103R0/US041](https://wg21.link/p2103r0#US041)).

Comment: What if `value_type` doesn't satisfy requirements for implicit lifetime start? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The lifetime of any element doesn't automatically begin, and hence placement new or `construct_at` call is needed to start its lifetime. IIUC P0593 has permitted the situation that "the lifetime of a complete object implicitly begins, while its subobjects do not".

Comment: Oh! So the lifetime of the array always starts, even if the lifetime of the elements doesn't?

Comment: Yes. This is required for the `allocate` function of an allocator.